# javascript change event does not work on angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am exploring jqLite and trying to understand how AngularJS works when doing DOM manipulation and general plain JavaScript stuff. Basicly I have been trying to bind events to different elements and so far it has worked good. blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave they all work when doing .on('event', handler) on an element except for the 'change' element on an input field.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('jqLite', jqLite);

/* @ngInject */
function jqLite () {

    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<h1>jqLite</h1>',
            '<input type="text" ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="jqLiteInput">',
            '<span style="background: red;">#<span>',
            '<!-- a comment -->'
        ].join(''),
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var input = element.find('input');

            /* AngularJS also has directives like
            ng-blur ng-focus ng-mouseenter ng-mouseleave but I can bind all of these events
            with .bind() or .on() method as I would usually do on jQuery */

            input.on('focus', function () { console.log(element.contents()); });
            input.on('blur', function () { console.log(element.html()); });

            //input.on('change', function () { console.log('this does not work'); });

            // this works
            scope.onChange = function () { console.log(scope.jqLiteInput + ' ' + element.children()); };

        }
    };

}
```

This is really weird and I hope someone could give me some tips on this one.

Comment: When do you expect the `change` event to fire for input fields?

Comment: when it's value changes, is that not what change is for? also when the value of a select element changes

Comment: It seems working fine here : http://jsbin.com/yitibo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: In case you want to run the change function as the value changes, use keyup event instead

Comment: I know that keyup works, so does alot of other events, but not change. I am wondering why change does not work.

Comment: Sorry I totally misunderstood change here. I know why change seem like it does not work, because it does not fire until you blur out of the input field. I completely missed this one! Thanks everyone!

Comment: You might want to post an answer to your own question, explaining what the problem was and what its solution is :)